# Cakephp Fatal Error not showing exact issue

Tags: php, cakephp, fatal-error

Im building an application, and when I'm writing code sometimes I get a Fatal error because of bad typo.

But CakePHP only shows Fatal Error in the Error Handler:

```
Error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleException() must be an instance of Exception, instance of ParseError given in C:\wamp\www\otras\becrm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\BaseErrorHandler.php:153 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler->handleException(Object(ParseError)) #1 {main} thrown 
File C:\wamp\www\otras\becrm\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\BaseErrorHandler.php 
Line: 153
```

Is there a way that it shows me something like Error in File "AppController"       Line 53? Where the real problem is?

error level in config/app is 'errorLevel' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED,

Comment: Start by upgrading your CakePHP installation. PHP7 error handling is supported as of CakePHP 3.1.5

Comment: is there a work around? i am on cakephp 3.0.7, i dont want to break any code that is working

Comment: That sounds as if your code isn't covered by tests? If it where, you could simply upgrade, run the tests, fix if something is broken, or rollback if necessary. 3.1 is fully API compatible, so there shouldn't be big problems, if any at all. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-1-migration-guide.html